# async code not being cleared in timeout function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, settimeout, cleartimeout

I've encountered and error in my react application regarding async calls in setTimeout function. Basically I have a condition when I want to clear the timeout but for some reason the code inside it still executes after it is cleared(I'm positive the condition is met). I have a codesandbox link of the app below. The thing is, when I input something and get a result, then click load more button, then before it finishes loading I add one more letter to the input, it says it's searching for the latest input but I actually get 2 results of the previous input and after a few seconds I get the result matching the latest input. Inside useEffect I check if it is loading, if it is I clear the timeout but it clearly does not work. Is there a way to solve this problem?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-diffie-uuzv19?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import SearchResult from "./SearchResult";

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const page = useRef(2);
  let timeout1 = useRef(null);

  const fetchData = async (filter, page = 1) => {
    if (filter === "") return;
    try {
      console.log(filter);
      const perPage = 1;
      const res = await axios.get(
        `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${filter}+in%3Alogin&page=${page}&per_page=${perPage}`
      );
      setLoading(false);
      return res.data.items;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) {
      clearTimeout(timeout1.current);
      console.log(timeout1.current);
      console.log("aborted");
    }
    const timeOut = setTimeout(async () => {
      if (filter) {
        const users = await fetchData(filter);
        console.log(users);
        setUsers(users);
      }
    }, 4800);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeOut);
      console.log(loading);
    };
  }, [filter]);

  const handleFilter = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFilter(e.target.value);
      setLoading(true);
      setUsers([]);
    }, 2000);
  };

  const handleLoad = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    timeout1.current = setTimeout(async () => {
      const res = await fetchData(filter, page.current);
      console.log(res);
      setUsers([...users, ...res]);
      page.current += 1;
    }, 6000);
  };

  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <input onChange={(e) => handleFilter(e)} />

      <div className="people">
        {users ? (
          users.map(({ login, avatar_url, html_url }) => {
            return (
              <SearchResult
                key={login}
                name={login}
                url={avatar_url}
                githubUrl={html_url}
              />
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
        {users.length > 0 && loading === false ? (
          <button onClick={handleLoad}>load more</button>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
        {loading ? <Loading filter={filter} /> : <></>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code directly in the question.  Then update your answer to include the code you changed to make it work.  Great job fixing your own issue, but Stack Overflow is about creating a reference for future visitors to solve their issues based on previous solutions.  This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to use .current when working with references and it wasn't working because of that.